# jQuery doesn't work but no mistakes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Good day anyone who is reading. I'm asking for help in situation that I can't solve.... Please help me.
   I have a php file, *main.php* there is a button, that create frame loaded from *frame.html*. created by javascript (original :) (not jquery)). Also to take check the form on frame I use jQuery. in result we have three files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/frame.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framejq.js"></script>
```

However when I loaded page and/or frame, debuger on Firefox show only two files - jquery.js and frame.js. (not framejq.js).  If I add code from framejq.js to frame.js - the frame.js is stop working and doesn't create frame at all. I mean jquery is working but the file is not. I even try add  in framejq.js next code :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//some code
});
```

But it doesn't help. it is still doesn't work. I tried different jquery libraries. But I can"t find why it doesn't work.

frame.js - create frame and loaded it from frame.html

```
function frame_reg () {
     reg=document.createElement('iframe');
     document.body.appendChild(reg);
     reg.id='iframe';
     reg.src='frame.html';
     // some manipulations
     return false;
}
```

framejq.js - work with form in frame

```
$(function() {
   $('.error').hide();
   $(".button").click(function(){
     var name = $("input#username").val();
     if (name== "")
        { $("label#username_error").show();
          $("input#username").focus();
          return false; }
      // other similar options
   });
});

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sign_up.php",
   data: datastr,
   success: close_frame
});
```

Here is the main things in files the rest is the similar or just function for change css files. Please help me find out the problem.

The problem that browser somehow doesn't load a framejq.js.  It doen't see it. If I put the code from framejq.js to frame.js. Frame.js stop working, the browser stop see it too...

pictures:

http://postimg.org/image/l30ax1z8f/
http://postimg.org/image/a4d0ydr6j/

Comment: Pretty sure `success: close_frame();` needs to be `success: close_frame` for a start. You want to assign the function, not call it.

Comment: In framejq.js the `$.ajax` misses 2 commas at `type` and `url`, also what does the debug console says (Press F12 and than switch to Tab "Console"), also you have a semicolon `;` after `close_frame()`, but that shouldn't be after an object.

Comment: Are you missing coma (`,`) after the Post statement? `type: "POST",` ?

Comment: what did you get in your borwser's console?

Comment: Not sure there's "no mistakes" as the title reads :)

Comment: @alex_mike you really want to check out your console. It's certainly yelling about syntax errors.

Comment: That is my problem I can't fix any mistakes because the framejq.js doesn't load , it shows only two of three files frame.js , jquery.js ... The debuger shows no mistakes at all because it doesn't see the file.

Comment: Can you also try loading the page in Chrome with the F12 debug tools open and check the network tab there. See if you get a 404 for the missing file,or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing 2 commas and are calling the `:success` function immediately and have a trailing semi-colon after that call. Your console should have been yelling syntax errors at you, so best check your tools first :)

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sign_up.php",
   data: datastr,
   success: close_frame
});
```

You need to specify the function by name and not call it.

The usual way of providing callbacks is with an anonymous function wrapper like this:

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sign_up.php",
   data: datastr,
   success: function(data){
       close_frame();
   }
});
```

but if the parameters are not used, or the called function has a matching number  of parameters, you can short-cut it to the first version (just supplying the function name).

Comment: That is my problem I can't fix any mistakes because the framejq.js doesn't load , it shows only two of three files frame.js , jquery.js ... The debuger shows no mistakes at all because it doesn't see the file.

Comment: @alex_mike: That is a completely different question now. Can you provide a screenshot of your folder contents and the full page HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Easier to explain here, you seem to be missing commas here...

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST"
   url: "sign_up.php"
   data: datastr,
   success: close_frame();
});
```

Should be...

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sign_up.php",
   data: datastr,
   success: close_frame
});
```

Comment: I'd only removed the parenthesis, forgot about the `;`, I fixed it now.  I was rushing to get the answer up :)

Comment: The downvoter should nonetheless have said _why_ they downvoted, so christiandev could improve his answer.

Comment: Fair enough. So I did, and yours too because it's the same ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to access elements inside the iframe from code on the containing page, try using `$('#iframe').contents()` like the below. But you also need to fix the two missing commas and fix the `success` callback so it's not calling the function immediately.:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var name = $('#iframe').contents().find("input#username").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $('#iframe').contents().find("label#username_error").show();
            $('#iframe').contents().find("input#username").focus();
            return false;
        }
        // other similar options
    });
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sign_up.php",
    data: datastr,
    success: function(info) {
        close_frame();
    }
});
```

Comment: Missed the `success` callback being wrong, fixed it